# hide specific categories from showing

Tags: categories

I'm trying to hide specific categories from showing up on a portfolio home page.
I was told that this was the concerned line of code on the php template file

```
<span class="entry-skills"><?php the_terms($post->ID, 'skill-type', '', ', ', ''); ?></span>
```

but there is no way to exclude certain types from this function by default. I would need to create a custom function in order to do so.

since I don't know much about php, I was thinking maybe some kind of expert could help me over here ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so it might need to be tweaked (specifically, I'm not sure if I got the names of the params right on the term object), but this should get you most of the way there.

```
//add filter
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'my_exclude_terms', 10, 1 );
//function to do filtering
function my_exclude_terms( $terms ) {
    //only filter for the homepage
    if( is_home() ) { // you may want to use is_front_page(), depending on your settings
        //list the unwanted terms
        $unwanted_terms = array( // fill this array with the unwanted term ids, slugs, or names
            14,
            18
        );
        // loop through the terms
        foreach( $terms as $k => $term ) {
            //only remove term if it's ID or slug is in the array.
            if(
              in_array( $term->term_id, $unwanted_terms, true ) || //comment out this line to remove term ID checking
              in_array( $term->slug, $unwanted_terms, true ) ||    //comment out this line to remove slug checking
              in_array( $term->name, $unwanted_terms, true )       //comment out this line to remove name checking
            ) {
                unset( $terms[$k] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

I used the `get_the_terms` filter because it's the last filter before the terms are turned to HTML, which makes it significantly more difficult to parse. If you're a complete novice with PHP and need help troubleshooting or implementing, post a comment. Good luck!

Comment: hello thank-you so much this piece of code rocks and hides the skills from showing but it actually hides every type of categories, I was attempting to hide only a certain type of - I have deactivated it here for you to see (http://www.madu.fr/portfolio/) actually it's only certain skills under each portfolio thumbs that I would like to hide - with the code you gave me it hides every type...

Comment: lol oops, I dropped a line of code, try it now.

Comment: nothing happens now :( function.php is the place to put that code right ? for example i'm trying to hide the "x da" cat witch has the id 126 - but nothing happens now with that new line...

Comment: did you update the `$unwanted_terms` array with the slugs or term ids for you unwanted terms? I'm going to check that `$term->ID` is correct real quick, but slugs should be working.

Comment: Turns out it's $term->term_id, so ids and slugs should both be working on that script.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it - I'm having difficulties for implementing this... I tried changing the `$term->term_id` by the id of the unwanted term, or elsewhere but nothing changes or I have Parse error.. let's say the 2 terms I wan't to hide is id "126" and "127" and there slugs are respectively "cd-rom" and "internet" what should the code be ? this is for example, knowing i'm going to need to hide more than two terms... thank you for your patience :)

Comment: All you should need to do is set `$unwanted_terms = array( 126, 127 )` to achieve that. Alternatively you can set `$unwanted_terms = array( 'cd-rom', 'internet' )` or even `$unwanted_terms = array( 126, 'internet' )`, make sure you're using the most recent edit of the code. I'll try to do some testing on this as soon as my schedule allows.

Comment: thank you for your testing and reply - this is what I exactly did with the most recent edit of the code, but the terms still won't get excluded... I've posted that same code on the support forum of this premium theme i'm customizing, I'l get back to you if I have any reply on this. cheers

Comment: ...I couldn't get any help from the support forum... If you could do some testings your side as you said, I would appreciate this very much. thanks

Comment: Huzzah! I have emerged victorious. Code is now working. It wasn't liking passing the term object as a variable, so I switched that up, fixed the slug checking, added name checking, and made it ACTUALLY remove it from the returned array! If you have any issues, the first thing you should try is making `is_home()` into `is_front_page()`, depending on how your WP install is setup, one of these will work and one may not. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hourrra !! it works !!! actually I changed `is_home()` into `is_page_template('template-home.php')` knowing that is the concerned home page template. Thank you so much ! this piece of code is going to change my life !